# Question about dhcp server in ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: dhcp

I configured a dhcp server , i then configured a client to take a dhcp ip .

I need from server terminal to know the addresses released to my domain Pcs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file when you install dhcp which is located at :

```
/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

Open the file you will find each node and the ip assigned for it .